# ActiveRecord - Building and saving parent/child associations simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have a `User` model and each `user` `has_many` `pets`.

If I'm building a new `User` model, how do I simultaneously build an associated `Pet` at the same time?

I tried -

```
user = User.new(name: "Foo Bar", age: 27)
pet_attributes = { type: "dog", breed: "Golden Retreiver" }
pet = user.pets.build(pet_attributes)
user.save!
```

The above fails because the `Pet` model has a foreign key - `user_id` - that is not populated when I build the object. It can't be, since the `user` model itself has no `id` yet because it's not saved to the DB.

So how do I save the `user` model and then have that `user_id` get populated in the `pet` model and save that, all in one go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested attributes, define `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your `user` model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets
```

Now you need to set nested parameters for pets, so that your parameters should be

```
user_params = {:name => "Foo Bar", :age => 27, :pets_attributes => [{ type: "dog", breed: "Golden Retreiver" }]}
```

Now pass this param to your model

```
user = User.new(user_params)
user.save!
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still results in the same error: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Pets user can't be blank`. Looks like it's still looking for the `user_id` on the `Pet` model.

Comment: can you please share your `pets` model?

Comment: If you have the validation on `Pet` model `validates_presence_of :user_id`, then you need to replace it with `validates_presence_of :user`. And you also need to use `inverse_of` in your defined associations. So your `User` model will looks like `has_many :pets, inverse_of: :user`, and your `Pets` model will be `belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :pets`.

Comment: Ah yes I did have that `presence` validation. Changing that plus the `inverse_of` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: For anyone else curious why this works the way it does: https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations